# *((type *) x) vs (* (type *)x)? to cast into pointer and then dereference in C

Tags: c, dereference

To cast a variable a[1] to a pointer and then dereference it in C, it seems both the formats work. For example,

> 1. *( (unsigned int *) a[1])
> 2. (*(unsigned int *) a[1])

Are they both correct? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: On their own they are equivalent but in real code you would have to be wary of [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The second option would (*in my opinion*) be better to use since it does the dereference in its own expression so the result isn't affected by operator precedence where as code like `*((someStruct*)x)->ptr` would be.

Comment: Why not just `*(unsigned int *)a[1]`?

Answer (score 3):

They are identical if you consider them as full independent expressions, or if surrounding context on the right-hand side is of sufficiently low precedence (does not intrude into the expression, since its precedence is lower than that of dereference operator `*`).

Otherwise, the second version has a pair of `()` around the cast expression which "isolates" it from surrounding context. For example, postfix operators, which have highest priority, will affect he semantics of these two expressions differently

```
*((unsigned int *) a[1])[M]
// Dereference is applied to the result of `[M]`

(*(unsigned int *) a[1])[M]  
// `[M]` is applied to the result of dereference
```

The resultant expressions are not necessarily valid, but they still illustrate the difference in operator-operand grouping. E.g. in case of integral `M`, the first expression is valid, the second isn't. In case of pointer `M` it is the other way around.